# What's the usage of Easymock.and(int, int)?

Tags: easymock

EasyMock has predefined argument matcher `and(X first, X second)`

Document says:

> Matches if the matchers used in first and second both match. Available for all primitive types and for objects.

But I don't understand what's the use case for the numberical type and matcher. For example, [`and(int first, int second)`](http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.0/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#and%28int,%20int%29), it's meaningless if first not equals to second, how can an integer equals both first and second while first and second are different value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is to use other matchers inside the and. Like and(lt(8), gt(4))